# Excel 2013 reduce concatenated decimals

Tags: excel, decimal, concatenation, excel-2013

My intention is to display both the min and max values from a small data set in one cell, which I've already accomplished by using the concatenate function:

```
=min(A1:A23)& - max(A1:A23)
```

But the function displays all of the decimals (the values in range are the result of another function, a division) and I can't reduce the quantity of decimals in the cell.

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaELn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace your function with

```
=Round(Min(A1:A23),2)&"-"&Round(max(A1:A23),2)
```

Then you will get the results 5,23-10,74 which is, I presume what you are looking for. The documentation for the Round function is here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c. You can change the number of decimals to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=ROUND(MIN(A1:A23);2) & " - " & ROUND(MAX(A1:A23);2)
```

Change the `2` to the number of decimals desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *TEXT()* function:

```
=TEXT(MIN(A1:A23),"0.000") & " - "&TEXT(MAX(A1:A23),"0.000")
```

[image]

Change the format mask to display exactly what you want.